# Webcomic set in a world of fairy tales. Included an overly clingy Beast, a psycho Red Riding Hood, and The Girl With the Silver Hands

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, fairy-tales

I was recently reading a new webcomic, and it made me briefly recall another webcomic I read, probably in the early 2000s, maybe on Keenspace or Keenspot. It was set in a world where the fairy tales were (largely) true, although they worked a bit differently. I don't remember if the protagonist was a known fairy tale character. If they were, I think they were minor. Early in the series, they run into the characters of *Beauty and the Beast*, with a small twist that the Beast tries to appear to be a violent jealous husband, but is actually very clingy, and cowed by Belle. Later, they encounter "Little Red Riding Hood", who's a psychotic killer with a penchant for axes. I remember that she was often shown with her hood/cloak, and the blood, being the only part in color, of course in red. At some point, they showed her "grandmother", who is a wizened corpse, who I think had been sewn back together into some semblance of humanity, but clearly dead for some time. Lastly, somewhere around when I stopped reading, I remember they encountered [The Girl with Silver Hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_Without_Hands), a tale I was unfamiliar with at the time. She was in a village, and had the silver hands, and seemed a sweet and giving soul. I don't recall if she had an arc, but I have a vague memory that there was something sinister going on that the rest of the village was engaged in.

The art-style was largely black-and-white, with the characters drawn in more of an anime-style, usually fairly simple lines, although I remember Beast being suitably detailed and hairy, Red Riding Hood and her grandmother drawn in very detailed style, and some very involved backgrounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're describing [*No Rest for the Wicked*](http://www.forthewicked.net/index.php), which started in 2003 and appears to have stalled as of 2012.  One difference from what you recall is that November (the central protagonist) and Perrault (a shape-changing cat) meet Red before they encounter Beast.

Red's cape is one of the only colored objects in the comic, and she carries an axe to kill things (especially talking animals):

[image: Red carrying her axe]

Beast is indeed drawn in a more detailed, less anime style:

[image: November meets Beast]

Beast is desperately in love with Beauty, who is in control of their relationship:

[image: Beast has proposed hundreds of times]

Visiting a town they meet Clare, the Girl With No Hands:

[image: Clare with her stumps in bandages]